# n'th derivative of a function that implement $y''-xy=0$

Tags: calculus

the function $y(x)$ implement the Equation $y''-xy=0$.

In addition, know that $y(0)=0 $ and $ y'(o)=1.$

find the value of $y^{(n)}(0)$, which means the value of 0 in the nth derivative.

**edit:tnx for the help**

i fix my soultion:

$y''-xy=0$ i add $xy$ to both sides and get

$y'' = xy$

now using lebniz rule
$
y^{(n+2)} = xy = ∑\left(\begin{array}{c}n\\ k\end{array}\right)x^{(n-k)}y^{(k)}
$
so i get

$y^{(3)}=y+xy′$
$y^{(4)}=2y′+xy′′$
$y^{(5)}=3y′′+xy′′′$

so i can see a pattern when i evaluate $x = 0$ and get the formula for $n>2$

$y^{(n)}=(n-2)y^{(n-3)}$

i know that $y(0)$ = $0$,$y$'$(0)$=$1$

so no the n order dervitive is

$f^{(3k)} = 0$

$f^{(3k+1)} =  \prod_{i=1}^{k-1}(3i−1)   $

$f^{(3k+2)} = 0$

Comment: I think it is $0$ when $n=3k+2$, and a recursive formula when $n=3k+1$. And you can just write that recursive formula as your answer.

Comment: yep my bad,i fix it and tnx for the answer

Comment: You can also write the result in a closed form expression $f^{(3k+1)}(0) = \prod_{i=1}^{k-1} (3i-1)$ if you feel like it.

Answer (score 0):

With the Frobenius method it is easy to check that, if
$$ f(x) = x + a_4 x^4 + a_7 x^7 + \ldots $$
and:
$$ a_{3k+1}3k(3k+1) = a_{3k-2} $$
then $f$ is a solution of the ODE satisfying the given constraints. This gives:
$$ f^{(n)}(0)\neq 0 \Longleftrightarrow n\equiv 1\pmod{3}, $$
and in such a case:
$$ f^{(3k+1)}(0) = \frac{a_{3k+1}}{(3k+1)!} = \frac{1}{\prod_{j=1}^{k}\left[(3k+1)^2(3k)^2(3k-1)\right]}.$$