# A version of Airy differential equation. Verify if $a_{n+3}=\frac{a_n}{(n+3)(n+2)}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $y''-xy=0$, $y(0)=\alpha$, $y'(0)=\beta$. Also, $y=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n x^n$ is a solution to y.

Then find the series $a_{n+3}$ and $a_{3n+2}$. Note that $a_n$ is a part of the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n x^n$

This is quite a shame, since I put in my title that I wanted to "verify" it - I actually haven't solved this question at all and was stuck for a long time. A friend helped out and claimed that $a_{n+3}=\frac{a_n}{(n+3)(n+2)}$, $a_{3n+2}=0 $ when $\alpha=0$ and $\beta=0$. Is this correct?

Comment: It is the Airy differential equation : see [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AiryDifferentialEquation.html). I have introduced this name in the title, if you don't object.

Comment: See as well [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1155097)

Answer (score 1):

As usual, if you let
$$y=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$$ you have
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty n(n-1)a_nx^{n-2}-\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^{n+1}=0$$ To consider the term $x^m$, the first summation requires $n-2=m$ (that is to say $n=m+2$ while the second requires $n+1=m$ (that is to say $n=m-1$).

So, for $x^m$, we have
$$(m+2)(m+1)a_{m+2}-a_{m-1}=0\implies a_{m+2}=\frac{a_{m-1}}{(m+1)(m+2) }$$ If you shift the index $(m=p+1)$, you have your relation
$$a_{p+3}=\frac{a_{p}}{(p+2)(p+3) }$$ Now, you need to take into account the conditions which give $a_0=\alpha$ and $a_1=\beta$ and then the two sets of parameters depending on the parity of $p$.

If you properly exploit the two reccurence relations, you should be able to show that
$$y=\alpha \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{3^{-2 n} \Gamma \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)}{\Gamma (n+1) \Gamma \left(n+\frac{2}{3} \right)}x^{3n}+ \beta \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{3^{-2 n}\Gamma \left(\frac{4}{3}\right)}{\Gamma (n+1) \Gamma   \left(n+\frac{4}{3}\right)}x^{3n+1}$$